# Mocha, array of array and scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, mocha.js

I have a code similar to this one:

```
let Foo = class Foo {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a.slice();
    }

    bar() {
        this.set(0, 1, [1]);
        this.set(1, 1, [1]);
    }

    set(x, y, n) {
        this.a[x][y] = n;
    }

    get() {
        return this.a;
    }
};

module.exports = Foo;
```

So a property whis is a array of array, a `set` function that modify it, and a function that use `set`, and a getter.

Now I write the unit tests, with mocha:

```
const Foo = require('./../foo.js'),
    source = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

describe('Foo', () => {
    describe('bar', () => {
        it('expect to modify the array', () => {
            let foo = new Foo(source);

            foo.bar();

            expect(foo.a).to.deep.equal([[1, [1], 3], [4, [1], 6]]);
        });
    });

    describe('get', () => {
        it('expect to return the array', () => {
            let foo = new Foo(source);
            expect(foo.get()).to.deep.equal([1, 2, 3]);
        });
    });
});
```

In which I declare the `source` variable at the beginning, and use it to build a new `Foo` each test.

However, the result is... that the `bar` test modify the property of the `foo` in the `get` test:

```
  Foo
    bar
      ✓ expect to modify the array
    get
      1) expect to return the array


  1 passing (19ms)
  1 failing

  1) Foo get expect to return the array:

      AssertionError: expected [ [ 1, [ 1 ], 3 ], [ 4, [ 1 ], 6 ] ] to deeply equal [ 1, 2, 3 ]
      + expected - actual

       [
      -  [
      -    1
      -    [
      -      1
      -    ]
      -    3
      -  ]
      -  [
      -    4
      -    [
      -      1
      -    ]
      -    6
      -  ]
      +  1
      +  2
      +  3
       ]

      at Proxy.assertEqual (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:1020:19)
      at Proxy.methodWrapper (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:57:25)
      at Context.it (test/foo.js:20:30)
```

Using anonymous function instead of arrow function in the mocha test doesn't change anything, using or not `splice` to copy the source by value either.

Did I missed something? It's obvious that I somehow attributed the same reference to the property of both `foo` to the same array, but I can't figure out how, and more importantly, how to ensure I can create separate the `foo`s.

Comment: @Jonasw in the real code, checks are made to ensure it doesn t fail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `this.a = a.slice()` only takes a shallow copy. But as `a` is a nested array, changing anything in the nested arrays will be visible in both `this.a` and `source`.

You could change:

```
this.a = a.slice();
```

to:

```
this.a = (function deepSlice(a) {
    return Array.isArray(a) ? a.map(deepSlice) : a;
})(a);
```

Note that your second test would need to be changed any way, since you are not comparing to what `source` was initialised to. So change:

```
expect(foo.get()).to.deep.equal([1, 2, 3]);
```

to:

```
expect(foo.get()).to.deep.equal([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
```

Comment: Tried with a simple `a.map((b)=>{return b.slice()})`, but it didn t worked, and thought I was going in the wrong direction, should have dwelled deeper

Comment: Yes it did, the mobile app didn't sent the green mark :)